# My init in viewModel calls print function three times

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui

I made a registration and login system with firebase. What is problem, when I click signout LoginViewModel call print function three times.

This is my code for LoginView:

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @State private var email: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    @State private var isSheet: Bool = false
    

    @ObservedObject var vm = LoginViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
    
            if vm.userStatus == true {
                HomeView()
            } else {
            ScrollView{
                NavigationLink(destination: HomeView().navigationTitle("").navigationBarHidden(true),
                               isActive: $vm.userStatus)
                {EmptyView()}
                VStack(spacing:35){
                    Text("")
                        .font(.system(size: 120))
                    
                    VStack(spacing:10){
                        Text("Socquote")
                            .font(.system(size: 32))
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                        
                        Text("Read and write personal quotes.")
                            .font(.system(size: 16))
                            .fontWeight(.light)
                    }
                    
                    VStack(spacing:20){
                        TextInput(text: $email, placeholder: "Email")
                        PasswordInput(password: $password, placeholder: "Password")
                    }
                    
                    GradientButton(title: "Login") {
                        loginUser()
                       
                    }
                    
                    HStack{
                        Text("You don't have account?")
                        Spacer()
                        LoginButton(name:"Sign Up", signUp: {showSheet()})
                    }.padding(25)
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $isSheet){
                    RegistrationView()
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth:.infinity)
       
            }
        
    }
    func showSheet() {
        isSheet.toggle()
    }
    
    func loginUser(){
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("There was an error while sign in. \(error)")
                return
            }
            
            print("User successfully logged in. \(result?.user.uid ?? "")")
            vm.userStatus.toggle()
           
        }
    }
}
```

This is HomeView:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm = LoginViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            if vm.userStatus == false{
                LoginView()
            }
            else{
            Button {
                vm.userStatus.toggle()
                logOut()
              
                print("This is from HomeView userstatus: \(vm.userStatus)")
                
            } label: {
                Text("Sign out.")
                }
            }
        }
            
    }
    
    func logOut(){
        try! Auth.auth().signOut()
    }
}
```

And finally this is the LoginViewModel:

```
class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userStatus = false
    @Published  var isShowingHomeView: Bool = false
    init() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.userStatus = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid != nil
            print("Comment from init LoginViewModel \(self.userStatus)")
        }

    }
}
```

I'm expecting  when I click signout, or log in, to only once call print function.

Comment: `vm` in  `LoginView` and `vm` in `HomeView` are two different instances. And use `@StateObject` instead of `@ObservedObject` if you initialize the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, you are creating two different instances of `LoginViewModel`, from `LoginView` and `HomeView`. Probably another piece of code somewhere is making one more instance of the view model.

I'd suggest if you want to create a single instance, either **pass it around the views** or have a **singleton** instance.